# Add grouping counter in drupal view twig template

Tags: drupal-9

I am trying to add counter in view grouping template but none of solution working from me
my  view grouping template:

> views-view-grouping--view_machine_name--block_machine_name.html.twig

```
<div class="view-grouping-header " id="grpup-{{ counter }}">{{ title }}</div>
<div class="view-grouping-content">{{ content }}</div>
```

Below are the variable i can user

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a single views grouping.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - view: The view object.
 * - grouping: The grouping instruction.
 * - grouping_level: A number indicating the hierarchical level of the grouping.
 * - title: The group heading.
 * - content: The content to be grouped.
 * - rows: The rows returned from the view.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_grouping()
 */
#}
```

I want output

```
<div class="view-grouping-header " id="grpup-1">{{ title }}</div>
<div class="view-grouping-content">{{ content }}</div>
```

> id="grpup-1" should be changes the number time occurred like 1 2 3 4 5